# google auth configuration issue in react app

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0

I am trying to create a login system in react using google auth. my code is below I am getting the below error, please check

> component file

```
export default class GoogleAuth extends Component {
    state = {isSignedIn:null}
    componentDidMount(){
        Window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
            Window.gapi.client.init({
                clientId:
                'my-----client-------id',
                scope: 'email'
            }).then(() => {
                this.auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                this.setState({isSignedIn:this.auth.isSignedIn.get()})
            })
        })
    }
    renderButton(){
        if(this.state.isSignedIn === null){
            return <div>I dont know if we are signed in </div>
        }else if(this.state.isSignedIn) {
            return <div>yes signed in </div>
        }else{
            return <div>I am not signed in </div>
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              {this.renderButton}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

> error message

[image]

if anyone knows please tell the issue

Answer (score 0):

instead of below code (Window function)

```
Window.gapi
```

I should have used window (instance of the Window function)

```
 window.gapi
```